# memcpy() not working as expected when copying pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy

I want to copy the content of a `char **pointer` to another pointer. My attempt was:

```
void test(char **arr, int len) {
    printf("1: ");
    printArr(arr, len);
    char ***res = malloc(sizeof(char **));
    res[0] = malloc(sizeof(char *) * len);
    memcpy(&res[0], arr, len);
    printArr(res[0], len);
```

Here I just wanted to copy the contents of `arr`, which holds several strings, to `r[0]` whereby `len` denotes the number of elements in `arr`. However, when inspecting `res[0]` I realised that it only stores two times null. As one can tell I'm a very beginner and have been learning C since a few days, so onc can expect simple mistakes.

Comment: Double pointers are already trouble. What's with the triple pointer(!!!) here? You only allocate one element, you only use one element. A one-element array should be a variable.

Comment: This code really doesn't make any sense at all. The more I look at it, the more I wonder what is going on. How is this used? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: @tadman the triple pointer should point to the different string arrays. I create different string arrays and want to check whether they were not already created, so I store them in res to remember which string arrays are already created. This might seem inefficient but since it's a dynamic application with user input I didn't find a simpler solution yet

Comment: *I realised that it only stores two times null*. What is it supposed to store? We can't tell from this incomplete code snippet. Please provide complete code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also include the exact expected result vs actual result.

Comment: An array of length one *is not really an array*.

Comment: Now I'm seeing that not only do you go through a lot of unnecessary fuss to allocate a length-1 array-that-is-not-an-array, but you copy `arr` to it, and then **throw that pointer into the void** by not returning it, not releasing it, and in fact, never actually doing anything with it. This code could be replaced with `return;` and it would do the same useful work. **Please explain what this is supposed to do.**

Comment: @tadman I'm doing a lot with it afterwards but to simplify the problem I reduced it to the above code snippet.

Comment: @tadman I provided my hole code now

Comment: There's even more confusion in this code. You're assigning to things (`res[size-1] = malloc(sizeof(char));`), then immediately stomping them with other values (`res[size-1] = dest;)`. Please, for your own sake, break this down into smaller problems and proceed more carefully.

Comment: I think a lot of the problems here stem from the fact that your code is extremely dense and cluttered. Let it breathe. Open it up a little. Break things into smaller, more readily understood functions. **Test these functions individually before using them**.

Comment: Like why do you have your own `strComp()` here when `strcmp()` exists and has existed since the 1970s? There's a lot of code here that shouldn't exist. It's just in the way.

Comment: @tadman that's what I was trying to do. But you said it's out of context, this conversation is a bit circular. I already tested all functions and that's why I provided a **small** code snippet

Comment: Sorry: None. Of. This. Code. Makes. Any. Sense.

Comment: @tadman because as I said in my post, I'm a beginner with C so I wanted to create them on my own

Comment: If you're learning C that's great, but I think you've learned enough C to be dangerous and it's showing. What you need to do is reel that in, use the tools you're given, don't reinvent the wheel. Stick to the fundamentals. C is simple superficially, but can get complex and confusing if you don't keep it under control.

Comment: Academic excursions like re-implementing `strcmp()` is fine, but in this context it just distracts from whatever core issue you're having. When you're stuck on a problem: Simplify. Remove things. Boil things down to their essentials. Strip away anything not strictly necessary. This `strComp()` served its purpose and now it can go.

Comment: that's why I only provided the small code at first!

Comment: I'm *trying to figure out what this code does*. You've got so many layers of "what???" I have to sift through here.

Comment: A) I think you're less of a beginner than you think, since this is not beginner-level code. B) I'm trying to unwind the "Why?" stack here by getting to the core of the problem, this is what we do when faced with code that doesn't make any sense. Try not to get all defensive. Just explain as best you can. C) Sorry if this came across as abrasive.

Comment: I'm a beginner with C (literally 4th day), but have already programmed in Java and Python for half a year, which are however very different to C. Also, my code does make sense, even if you don't want to believe it, at least the part that doesn't depend on what my problem was about. That the part with memcpy() doesn't make any sense is because I'm using it the first time so yes, it might not make any sense

Comment: @tadman the mistake was very simple, as I misunderstood the memcpy() function. For the next time consider to e.g. instruct the OP about the functions of concern so a solution can be found quickly. Moreover, sorry for my impertinence, but I was just a bit confused why you commented all the time that everything didn't make any sense whereby all functions work fine...

Comment: While I'm willing to admit fault here in terms of approach, your explanation really doesn't make any sense, and doesn't even refer to the same variables as appear in the code (we must presume `r` means `res` for instance). Where words fail, we turn to code, and that code makes even less sense, I wasn't sure what the intent was. This is why having a *minimal* example of what you're trying to do, ideally just 10-15 lines tops, helps communicate very clearly, even in the absence of a complete, written description. A sample call to this function and expected results is all we ask for.

Comment: When dealing with nested pointers and memory allocation it's very important to understand a lot when it comes to intent and use: Do you want a shallow copy (just the top layer) or a deep copy? Are you re-sizing the original and replacing it, or making an independent, new copy? Do you need or have a function to clean up these allocations later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char ***res = malloc(sizeof(char **));
res[0] = malloc(sizeof(char *) * len);
memcpy(&res[0], arr, len);
```

The first line allocates space for a single `char **` and makes `res` point at it

The second line allocates space for an array of `len` pointers to `char` and makes `res[0]` point at it.

The third line copies len byes from arr over the top of the memory pointed at by `res`, overwriting the result of the second malloc call and then scribbling over memory after the block allocated by the first malloc call.

You probably actually want something like

```
mempy(res[0], arr, len * sizeof(char*));
```

which will copy an array of `len` pointers (pointed at by arr) into the memory allocated by the second malloc call.

Comment: unfortunately, your solution gives me a SEG FAULT when trying to print the first string of the copied array with `printf("%s", res[0][0]);`. `arr` is of the form {"ab", "bc", "cd"}

Comment: That probably means `arr` is incorrect (or `len` is wrong), or you are passing it incorrectly to your function.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an array of C strings that you need *deep copied*:

```c
char** array_deep_copy(char **arr, int len) {
    // calloc() makes "allocation of N" calculations more clear
    // that this is N allocations of char* becoming char**
    char **res = calloc(len, sizeof(char*));

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
      // Use strdup() if available
      res[i] = strdup(arr[i]);
    }

    return res;
}
```

Note that this needs a proper release function that will go through and recursively `free()` those cloned strings or this *leaks memory*.

If you only need a shallow copy:

```c
char** array_shallow_copy(char **arr, int len) {
    char **res = calloc(len, sizeof(char*));

    // memcpy(dest, src, size) is usually more efficient than a loop
    memcpy(res, arr, sizeof(char*) * len);

    return res;
}
```

This one doesn't need a recursive `free()`, you can just `free()` the top-level pointer and you're done. This one shares data with the original, so if *any* of those pointers are released before this structure is then you'll have invalid pointers in it. Be careful!